# LimitInternalRecursion error

Tags: multisite

Sorry for this dumb question. Actually, I am not a Wordpress Developer and I have no idea what following code does in .htaccess file.

I am getting many errors like this:

`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace`

`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://website.com/wp-admin/customize.php?theme=handystore&return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fthemes.php%3Factivated%3Dtrue`

From blogs, I understood above errors are linked with following rewrite conditions in .htaccess files. This whole content is generated through plugins and is left over of some of the plugins.

```
# Start BWP Minify WP Rules 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(cache/minify-.*\.(js|css))$ $2 [L]
</IfModule>
# END BWP Minify WP Rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

please help in resolving above errors.

Comment: How about refreshing the permalinks? The above .htaccess file contains various rules that are introduced by WordPress , do you manually add them?

Answer (score 1):

I removed following lines and errors vanished.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```